# Style with image as parameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, blend

I wonder how can i parametrize an image source inside an style, and this style is used inside another style. Let me try to be more clear.
I defined an style for buttons, the style has an image. Then i have another style. On that style, I have two buttons (i´ve applied the button style), and i want to able to change the image of each button. But i can´t get it work.

The first part of the code defines a style for a button the idea is to change the image as needed to represent an action.

This is my code:

```
<Style x:Key="InnerInscribirseButtonMatch" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOver">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Blur_back">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="-0.666"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Blur_back">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.705"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="2.665"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="2.999"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Blur_back">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFE9E9A7"/>
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="#FFF1F0DD"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="3"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="4"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF356AA0"/>
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="#FF1264B6"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Blur_back" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5" Stroke="#FF3F4C6B" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#FF5B8BBC" Margin="-4.5,-4" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <Rectangle.Effect>
                                <BlurEffect Radius="7"/>
                            </Rectangle.Effect>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Back" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5" Stroke="#FF3F4C6B" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#FF356AA0"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Glass" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5" Stroke="#FF3F4C6B" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="White" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.15" Margin="0,0,0,61" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="13.766,0,15.766,14.351" d:LayoutOverrides="Width">
                            <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.77"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Effect>
                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <Image x:Name="image" Margin="12,3.5,17,22.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="64" Height="64" Source="apuntarlista.png">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseDown">
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="MouseOver_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOver}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseUp">
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOver_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOver_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsCancel" Value="False"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

well, this is the part i want to customize. The source part: *Source="apuntarlista.png"*

```
<Image x:Name="image" Margin="12,3.5,17,22.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="64" Height="64" Source="apuntarlista.png">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
```

here, you have the second style

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleCambiable" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Height="130" Width="Auto" Margin="50,0,-315,0">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="background" Fill="{Binding BackgroundColor, FallbackValue=#FF932424}" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Stroke="{Binding BorderBackgroundColor, FallbackValue=#FF954444}" StrokeThickness="3" Height="130" Width="375" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="white_glass" Fill="White" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="3" Opacity="0.07" Height="65" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ClipToBounds="True" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,13.901,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="272" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="48" FontFamily="Cambria" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Description, FallbackValue=50/100}" FontWeight="Bold">
                            <TextBlock.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3" Opacity="0.35" BlurRadius="13"/>
                            </TextBlock.Effect></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="206,14.192,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="122" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Cambria" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="En espera: " d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment">
                            <TextBlock.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3" Opacity="0.35" BlurRadius="13"/>
                            </TextBlock.Effect></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,50.123,0,51.739" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="109" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Cambria" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Libres: " d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, Height">
                            <TextBlock.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3" Opacity="0.35" BlurRadius="13"/>
                            </TextBlock.Effect></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="292,51.123,0,50.739" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Cambria" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding FreeSits, FallbackValue=10}" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, Height">
                            <TextBlock.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3" Opacity="0.35" BlurRadius="13"/>
                            </TextBlock.Effect></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="329,15.192,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="96" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Cambria" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding PeopleWaiting, FallbackValue=1}" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment">
                            <TextBlock.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3" Opacity="0.35" BlurRadius="13"/>
                            </TextBlock.Effect></TextBlock>
                        <Button Content="Inscribir" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="381,2,0,2" Style="{DynamicResource InnerInscribirseButtonMatch}" Width="129" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.85"/>
                        <Button Content="Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="518,2,0,2" Style="{DynamicResource InnerInscribirseButtonMatch}" Width="129" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.85"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

there i have:

```
<Button Content="Inscribir" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="381,2,0,2" Style="{DynamicResource InnerInscribirseButtonMatch}" Width="129" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.85"/>

<Button Content="Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="518,2,0,2" Style="{DynamicResource InnerInscribirseButtonMatch}" Width="129" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.85"/>
```

as you can see both buttons use Style="{DynamicResource InnerInscribirseButtonMatch}"

but i want each one to have a diferent image.

How can i do that? I Hope to be clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can define `Button.DataContext` property, for example, by string, and bind the `Image.Source` property with control DataContext.

```
<Button DataContext="apuntarlista.png"
        Style="{DynamicResource InnerInscribirseButtonMatch}"
         />

<Button DataContext="apuntarlista2.png"
        Style="{DynamicResource InnerInscribirseButtonMatch}"
         />
```

And in your inner style:

```
<Image x:Name="image" 
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
       Width="64" Height="64" Source="{Binding}">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO i would always try to not change the style so that is needs specific input. Thats what the `Content` is for and the `ContentTemplate`.
But of course this is difficult sometimes.

We use for these cases an AttachedProperty

So make a new static class name it for example `ButtonIconService`. give it an [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) named `Icon`

set it on your buttons like

```
<Button ButtonIconService.Icon="pathToIcon.png"
<Button ButtonIconService.Icon="pathToOtherIcon.png"
```

and bind it to your Image in your template.

```
<Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(ButtonInfoService.Icon)}}"
```

im not sure at the moments if the brackets around `ButtonInfoService.Icon` are needed?

Hope that helps.